# C++ overloading operator+ using a class and a int parameter as template

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend

i can't figure out what's wrong on this code:

```
template <class T = char, int num = 100> class Stack;
template <class T = char, int num1 = 100, int num2 = 100> Stack<T, num1>& operator+=(Stack<T, num1>& s1, const Stack<T, num2>& s2);
template <class T, int num>
class Stack{
template <T, int num1, int num2 > friend  Stack<T, num1>& operator+=(Stack<T, num1>& s1, const Stack<T, num2>& s2);
public:
   ...
private:
   Entry* first;
   class Entry{
      ...
   }
   void append(const Stack& s){
        if(isEmpty()) first = &s;
        else first->last().next = &s;
   }
   ...
};
template <class T, int num1, int num2>
Stack<T, num1>& operator+=(Stack<T, num1>& s1, const Stack<T, num2>& s2){
    s1.append(Stack<T, num2>(s2));
    ...
};
```

The point is that i've already set the friendship from the class to the operator, and i'm still getting `error: 'append' is a private member of 'Stack<char, 100>'` so i'm doing something wrong on it, can someone please check this?

Comment: Consider making `operator+` be a non-static member of the `Stack` class instead, then it will have access to `append()` without needing to be a `friend`. For that matter, why not just move the `append()` logic into `operator+` directly? Or even better, add `operator+=` to the `Stack` class, and then have `operator+` (member or otherwise) call `operator+=`. It really doesn't make sense to have a private `append()` at all

Comment: It is unusual that `auto z = x + y;` will modify `x`!

Comment: @aschepler you are right, i was looking for +=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```cpp
template <T, int num1, int num2 > friend  Stack<T, num1>& operator+(Stack<T, num1>& s1, const Stack<T, num2>& s2);
```

declares an `operator+` function template that takes a value of type `T`, a value of type `int`, and another value of type `int` as template parameters as friend of your class template. Note how the function template you declared as friend is not the one you declared above the definition of `Stack`. The template argument lists are different. Above the definitionf of `Stack`, you declare:

```cpp
template <class T, int num1, int num2>
//           ^ type parameter
Stack<T, num1>& operator+(Stack<T, num1>& s1, const Stack<T, num2>& s2);
```

but in the friend declaration you declare

```cpp
template <T, int num1, int num2>
//        ^ non-type parameter
Stack<T, num1>& operator+(Stack<T, num1>& s1, const Stack<T, num2>& s2);
```

You'll have to write

```cpp
template <class U, int num1, int num2> friend Stack<U, num1>& operator+(Stack<U, num1>& s1, const Stack<U, num2>& s2);
```

to make your original `operator+` template a friend of the class template `Stack`…

Apart from all that, I would recommend that you stop right there and think about whether it really is a good idea that an expression like

```cpp
a + b
```

implicitly modifies `a`. If you really must use an operator for this, an `operator+=` is probably a better way to express these semantics (personally, I'd probably just stick with an append function here). Since an `operator+=` must be a non-static member function, your initial problem then also disappears…

Comment: oh you are absolutely right about the fact that "a" should remain equals... but about the template problem... so the problem was that instead of T i should had to use U because T was already referencing the template class of the class Stack? if i'm right, could i leave T on the declaration above the class and the implementation under the class, and use U only in the friendship, or i have to use the same letter everywhere?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia The problem was that inside your class template `Stack`, the identifier `T` denotes a type. Thus, if you write `template <T, ...>` then that first parameter is not a type, but a value of type `T` just like the first parameter in `template <int, ...` is a value of type `int`, not the type `int` itself…

Comment: …To make a template parameter a type, you have to write `template <class T, ...` or `template <typename T, ...` However, since `T` is already used as the first parameter of `Stack`, you cannot use it to name the first parameter of your friend [\[temp.local\]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.local#6). Thus you have to pick some other name. It's just a name anyways. Parameter names are not part of a signature. `template <class T> void f();` is the exact same template as `template <class U> void f();`…

Comment: well, thank you... just another question if i can... why can't i create this variable inside the operator? `Stack<U, num>::Entry * p = element.first;`

Comment: turns out i was missing the "typename" before it, also if i can't understand why i have to put it

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia `Stack<U, num>::Entry` is a dependent name. When parsing the template, the compiler cannot know whether `Stack<U, num>::Entry` is going to be a type or a static member or something. Because depending on what `U` and `num` are, a different specialization of `Stack` will be picked, for which `Stack<U, num>::Entry` could have entirely different meanings. Thus, you have to tell the compiler that `Stack<U, num>::Entry` is supposed to be a type name here…